# Using 'not only... but also'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, word-order

Could someone please suggest me which one of the below two options is correct in terms of usage of 'Not only but also'. Feel free to suggest an alternative option.

1. *Not only does it justice to both*, but also presents them in a way that they complement each other.

OR

2. *It not only does justice to both*, but also presents them in a way that they complement each other.

Following question - I am more inclined towards starting the sentence with 'Not only'. So if the first option is not correct, could you please help me with correctly framing one.

Comment: Your #1 has some missing words (eg *do* justice; *it* also). The form itself can be used either way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Lawrence.

Just to confirm, 'Not only does it do justice to both, but it also presents them in a way that they complement each other' should be correct, right?

Comment: Please also comment on the usage of comma in this sentence (#1). Thanks.

Comment: That sentence in your comment makes sense grammatically. The comma looks fine where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not only but also**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131463#eid33582359)

> 3. In correlative constructions using not only: usually with contrast expressed by but, but also, also, etc., but occasionally **implied**

As in:

> 1987   P. McCabe Bad News at Black Rock:    "Collins not only did
>   reviews, she incorporated bites from interviews into pieces."

and

> 2001   Daily Tel. 27 Nov.    "I want the courts to think very carefully
>   not only about perhaps not using custody but, if they can, issuing
>   shorter sentence lengths."

and

> 1548   Hall's Vnion: *Henry VI*    "Not onely now..but also after."

And lastly your sentence, modified:

> Not only does it do justice to both, but also presents them in a way
>   that they complement each other.